# Menuitems is not changed ,When I hover on MenuItems. on Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css

The code placed below I have a problem.
When I hover on Menu Items departmentsHover class  is not effect the menu Items.
The color and background image is not changed.

What must I do?

P.S I am using MS visual Studio 2010 and asp.net in the environment.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .departmentsHover
        {
            color:Red;
            padding-left:4px;
            background-color:green;
                background-image:url("tile.jpg");
            width:150px;
        }
        .departments
        {
            color:Black;
            background-color:red;
            margin:2px;
            padding:4px;
            width:100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server"  >


        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ada"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ada"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ada"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ada"></asp:MenuItem>

        </Items>

        <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="departments"/>
        **<StaticHoverStyle  CssClass="departmentsHover"/>**

        <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="mainmenu" />

    </asp:Menu>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this might help you http://forums.asp.net/t/1053609.aspx/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use css hover

```
.departments:hover
        {
            color:Red;
            padding-left:4px;
            background-color:green;
                background-image:url("tile.jpg");
            width:150px;
        }
```

Comment: Use firebug to track the attribute of the menu item when hover.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="departments" >
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ada"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ada"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ada"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="ada"></asp:MenuItem>

        </Items>    

</asp:Menu>
```

and in your style

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .departments:hover
        {
            color:Red;
            padding-left:4px;
            background-color:green;
            background-image:url("tile.jpg");
            width:150px;
        }
        .departments
        {
            color:Black;
            background-color:red;
            margin:2px;
            padding:4px;
            width:100px;
        }
    </style>
```